# Book recommendations and study aid; in need of a little help

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, self-learning, education, advice

Please excuse the placeholder header; I currently don't know what to put up there, yet I might change it in the near future!
Today, I wanted to make a slightly different post and instead of asking a question about a specific property or exercise, I'd like to ask if anyone has some great book recommendations for self-studying and practicing mathematics. I'm particularly interested in Linear Algebra, Calculus/Analysis, or anything that might spark one's interest. (I also enjoy books of an inspirational nature) :)
I recently went through an exam phase that, unfortunately, went very much sideways due to my overall psychological state of mind/health. Though it hasn't been an easy nor the best experience, I really don't want to give up on the joy that Mathematics and studying it brought into my life so far.
Any advice, recommendations, or further share of mind would as always be greatly appreciated and taken to heart. Additionally, a huge thank you to everyone out there posting interesting threads and wonderful content! I've been learning quite a lot of great things on here, which has been of great great help

Comment: Wow, this is the most wholesome post I've seen here in a while :) Not too sure whether this fits the community's expectation of what questions should be like so maybe the question will be closed (perhaps for being too broad), but just from one human to another, all the best! You might enjoy The Great Mathematical Problems by Ian Stewart - I found it a very enlightening and enjoyable read.

Comment: @YiFanTey I am really out of words, that comment really really made my day; Thank you so much, so so much and I will most certainly check out the book recommendation <3 Have a soothing day and thank you for being here !

Comment: You might enjoy Aigner and Ziegler, [Proofs from THE BOOK](https://www.google.ca/books/edition/Proofs_from_THE_BOOK/E6rvCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Aigner+Ziegler+%22Proofs+from+THE+BOOK%22&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @RobertIsrael That one looks incredibly interesting!! Thank you so so much <3 !!